# Check if API object exists before usage

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm fetching rss data from a news API. However, sometimes the entries have certain fields such as `image` or `summary`, and sometimes they do not. How can I check if the object is empty before calling it?

```
url = "http://rss.cnn.com/rss/cnn_topstories.rss"
feed = Feedjira::Feed.fetch_and_parse url
api_json = JSON.parse(feed.to_json)
data_array = []

feed.entries.each_with_index do |entry,index|
  data_array << { title: entry.title, link: entry.url, image_url: entry.image, summary: entry.summary }.as_json
end
```

In the above code, sometimes `entry.image` and `entry.summary` are empty and it returns an error such as:

```
undefined method `image' for #<Feedjira::Parser::ITunesRSSItem:0x007fb25c452688>
```

#### Current Attempt:

One obvious way is to check every object before saving it as a variable. But is this the best approach?

```
if entry.image.exists?
    image = entry.image
else
    image = ""
end
if entry.summary.exists?
    summary = entry.summary
else
    summary = ""
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `try()`, it will return `nil` if the associated property is missing

```
entry.try(:image)
```

In your code, you can do like this

```
data_array << { title: entry.try(:title), link: entry.try(:url), image_url: entry.try(:image), summary: entry.try(:summary) }.as_json
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. How does this compare to the answer suggested by @maximf. If I'm using the latest version of Ruby, is there a preference for which operator to use?

Comment: Both are same, maximf's answer is just an other way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Ruby 2.3.0 or higher you can make use of the brand new `Safe Navigation Operator`:

```
entry&.image # same thing as entry.try(:image) but shorter
```

You can even navigate as deep as you want, e.g.:

```
entry&.image&.urls&.small # Works as a charm even if "urls" is not present
```